# Module-Block not working in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to create new module in magento2. I am trying to  override the Review block but is not working. Please check and let me know what I am doing wrong:

**di.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View" type="Categoryreview\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

**Categoryreview/Block/Product/View.php** file code

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Revoamerica\Categoryreview\Block\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View {

public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    die("testtt");
    // if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
    //     $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
    //         $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    //     )->addStatusFilter(
    //         \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
    //     )->addEntityFilter(
    //         'product',
    //         3
    //         //$this->getProduct()->getId()
    //     )->setDateOrder();
    // }
    // return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}

}
```

**registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'xyz_Categoryreview',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: Add your namespace in type '<preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View" type="Namespace\Categoryreview\Block\Product\View" />'

Comment: i have added namespace but its now working

Comment: Add sequence tag in your module.xml. 
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
and run setup:upgrade command

Comment: I have added this code in module.xml file        
                                       
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Xyz_Categoryreview" setup_version="1.0.1" />
    <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Review" />
        </sequence>
</config>

Answer (score 2):

Modify the **di.xml** like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Review\Block\Product\View" type="Xyz\Categoryreview\Block\Product\View" />
</config>
```

Modify the path and content of **app/code/Xyz/Categoryreview/Block/Product/View.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Xyz\Categoryreview\Block\Product;

class View extends \Magento\Review\Block\Product\View {

public function getReviewsCollection()
{
    die("testtt");
    // if (null === $this->_reviewsCollection) {
    //     $this->_reviewsCollection = $this->_reviewsColFactory->create()->addStoreFilter(
    //         $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()
    //     )->addStatusFilter(
    //         \Magento\Review\Model\Review::STATUS_APPROVED
    //     )->addEntityFilter(
    //         'product',
    //         3
    //         //$this->getProduct()->getId()
    //     )->setDateOrder();
    // }
    // return $this->_reviewsCollection;
}

}
```

And **registration.php**

```
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Xyz_Categoryreview',
    __DIR__
);
```

Comment: its not working i have change accordingly and refresh cache but its not working its always call vendor review module code

Comment: Did you run setup upgrade, di compile?

Comment: yes i have run this command

Comment: Any other suggestion to me

Comment: It should work. Check the spellings

Comment: I have cross check all module files (NoT working)

Comment: Change Xyz to Revoamerica. you define your override as \Categoryreview\Block\..\..\View or whatever, but magento doesnt know what Categoryreview is, you need your full namespace.

Comment: @zack6849 Why need to change Xyz to Revoamerica? As I have already mentioned everything. Please check the answer properly.

Comment: Because, OP's code is in Revoamerica, not Xyz, your code keeps mentioning app/code/Xyz/Categoryreview/Block/Product/View.php as a placeholder, but if I read his question right, his module is app/code/Revoamerica/Categoryreview/Block/Product/View.php

Comment: Can you check his registration.php? Or you are not seeing anything?

Comment: I have replace xyz to Revoamerica every place and upgrade compile and refresh cache but i am getting same issue its not working

Comment: Sorry Shintu this comment is for zack